# Spring Boot UpdateDefinition behavior

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently working in a REST API, one of the entities i have to deal with is `Product` entity.
When I want to make a `PUT` request on a product document using the `UpdateDefinion` instance `Update`, I get a weird behavior in return

Product class:

```java
@Data
public class Product{
    // some attributes
    
    // some getters and setters
}
```

The update method on the ProductService class:

```java
public Product editAProduct(ObjectId pid, Product product){
        MongoOperations mongoOperations = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "milevdeli");
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(pid));
            Update update = Update.update("product", product);
                    .set("name", product.getName())
                    .set("type", product.getType())
                    .set("price", product.getPrice());

            mongoOperations.findAndModify(
                    query,
                    update,
                    FindAndModifyOptions.options().returnNew(true),
                    Product.class);

        return (Product) mongoOperations.find(query, Product.class).get(0);
```

My Products collection:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "name": "some name",
    "price": "some price",
    "type": "some type"
    
}
```

BUT i get something like this when I execute the request:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "name": "some name",
    "price": "some price",
    "type": "some type",
    "product": {
        "name": "new name",
        "price": "new price",
        "type": "new type",
      }
    
}
```

I was expecting only the fields update i requested

the Request Body:

```json
{
    "name":"Updated name",
    "price": "Updated price"
}
```

the response body:

```json
    "name":"Updated name",
    "price": "Updated price",
    "type":null
```

What i do not understand is:

- How the `update()` method works?
- How is it possible for it to "ignore" the fields not passed through the request body of the `PUT` request?
- Why is it adding an extra field for my mongoDB collection that actually has the modification sent in the request?
- Why is it setting the set fields with the `.set()` method but not passed through the request body to `null` and how to prevent that?

Comment: The `update` will update the key and the object you pass in the arguments.

Comment: The use of the verb PUT it is at the entry point level, you have to handle what you want it to do at the database level.

It is adding the "extra" field because it is part of the object Product and as I can see your request body only has two attributes therefore the `type` attribute will be null. Depending on your requirement you might need to get the original content and check what to update/what to keep in a `Product` object and pass it to the `UpdateDefinition` instance

Comment: it males sense to me, at first i thought that the `update()` method would update the whole document rather some fields, thank you.